# How do I solve this System of Equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, radicals

How do I begin to solve this system? $$x^2=y+a$$$$y^2=z+a$$$$z^2=x+a$$

Do I take the square roots of $x,y$ and $z$? If so, we get $$x=\pm\sqrt{a+y}$$$$z=\pm\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{a+y}}$$$$y=\pm\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{a\pm\sqrt{a+y}}}$$

What do I do now? I'm confused as to what to do.

Comment: Subtract the first and the third equations member to member: you obtain $x=y$. Then consider the second and third equations (with $x$ substituted with $y$). Subtract them member to member...

Comment: Edit the first equation where there is a typo.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the catch! Didn't notice that until now... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceeding from Sonnhard's solution, besides $z = (1 \pm \sqrt{1+4a})/2$ from the factor $-z^2 + z + a$, we get the two cubics 
$$z^3 + \frac{1\pm r}{2} z^2 + \frac{\pm r - 2a - 1}{2} z + \frac{a \mp ra -2}{2}$$
where $r = \sqrt{4a-7}$.  If you're interested in real solutions, you need $
a \ge -1/4$ for the first pair of solutions, and $a \ge 7/4$ for the cubics.

The solutions for $z = (1 \pm \sqrt{1+4a})/2$ have the same values for $x$ and $y$.  The solutions for the cubics have $x, y, z$ the three roots of the cubic, in decreasing order (or cyclically permuted).

Here's a plot: the black curve is $ z = (1 \pm \sqrt{1+4a})/2$, the red and blue curves are the roots of the two cubics.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from the first equation we obtain $$y=x^2-a$$ plugging this in the second one we get
$$(x^2-a)^2=z+a$$ with the third equation we get an equation only in $z$
$$((z^2-a)^2-a)^2=z+a$$

Comment: How to proceed after that?

Comment: factorizing the last equation we obtain $$ \left( -{z}^{2}+a+z \right)  \left( -{z}^{6}+3\,a{z}^{4}-{z}^{5}-3\,{
a}^{2}{z}^{2}+2\,a{z}^{3}-{z}^{4}+{a}^{3}-{a}^{2}z+3\,a{z}^{2}-{z}^{3}
-2\,{a}^{2}+2\,az-{z}^{2}+a-z-1 \right) 
=0$$

Comment: one factor you can solve the other equation is from degree six, there is no formula for this

Comment: Actually it seems the Galois group of that degree-$6$ factor is solvable, so there should be a solution in radicals.

Comment: In fact, it reduces to the two cubics: $$x^3 + \dfrac{r+1}{2} x^2 + \dfrac{r-2a-1}{2} x + \dfrac{a}{2} - \dfrac{ra}{2} - 1$$ and
$$ x^3 + \dfrac{-r+1}{2} x^2 + \dfrac{-r-2a-1}{2} x + \dfrac{a}{2} + \dfrac{ra}{2} - 1$$
where $r = \sqrt{4a-7}$.

Comment: $r$ exists not in every case